# What secret did David whisper to Meg at the end of "The Sculptor"?

Tags: comics, the-sculptor, scott-mccloud

Scott McCloud's *The Sculptor* opens with the following scene, where Meg asks David to whisper her something:

[image: Meg: "Tell me now. Whisper it in my ear"]
 <sub>Click for larger image</sub>

The scene is expanded at the very end of the novel, where Meg explains David that he can choose something the world *won't* remember about him - a secret that will die when Meg gets old and dies.

[image: Both lying in bed in their apartment. Meg: "Tell me a secret. Something you've never told anyone. Tell me so softly even that moth can't hear. After you're gone, I'll carry it inside of me. I'll think of it every day. But when I'm gone, the secret goes with me. Together, we'll let it die, just you and me. Not 'cause we're helpless in the face of time, but because we're giving ourselves to time with all our hearts." David: "Okay... a bit weird, but I like it. Let's do this."]
 <sub>Click for larger image</sub>

What did he whisper? At first I thought it would be "I love you", because he's a romantic, but then I realised they'd already exchanged those words; another secret I can think of is the details of his deal with Death, but he'd explained those as well by that time. What else could he have said?

*(Scott McCloud talks about this scene briefly in [this interview](http://www.tcj.com/scott-mccloud-unpacks-and-defends-the-sculptors-ending/) (obvious spoilers), but he doesn't reveal what David said)*